# Creating Azure Environments for Country-Specific Data?

Tags: sql, azure, privacy

We have an iOS app where users can register, login, and generally do user-specific stuff. We are currently hosting it in Azure SQL DB and using other Azure Services such as Web Applications, Azure Functions etc.

If we want to scale the app for different Countries, we are aware that there are different data privacy concerns per Country. As such, should we be creating different Azure Environments for each country? And develop different versions of the iOS app to point to the specific Azure Environment to use?

Is this is the correct practice? Or is there a recommended pattern / approach for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the requirement and the end customer, in some cases certain countries have common policies in place.

You can read and understand the [`best practices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/govern/guides/complex/) and [`Guidance for Data Controllers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/gdpr-dpia-azure)  when you are migrating/implementing applications on azure

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the main concern is data residency, because some data needs to be hosted only for that country as per the law.